# How to Get Model Object to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have an action like below in my controller and the object of one Viewmodel class i had send as an argumnet to view. The problem is i need to get this object values in 
javascript.

```
public ActionResult FillChecklist()
{
 classOne objVM=new classone();
    objVM.List=//get list 
    objVM.Id=//someid
    objVM.List2=//secondlist
 return View(objVM);
}
```

i had tried something like below but it does not works. i know hidden variable assign is a solution but i don't know if model class has many lists then how can i get the list in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var obj=@Model;

</script>
```

i had tried the below method too. but it shows the name json is not exist in this current context

```
var obj = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test for you with the following code:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.TestViewModel
@using System.Web.Helpers

<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
</script>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = JSON.parse('{"Test":"Value123"}');
</script>
```

Comment: it shows one more warning conditional compilation is turned off

Comment: I edited my answer and ran a test for you. This solution works 100%

Comment: i can't write JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'); it shows error like json does not exist in this corrent context that is my problem